# is there any jvm customization to call custom method other than main method?

Tags: java, security, jvm

I am working on a project for banking application, and I have been asked to provide some suggestions to increase the security of application. So I was thinking of customizing JVM on the server to make call some custom method of a Class.

eg : when I invoke 
*$ > java MyClass*

it should call a method like **public static void citiMain(String[] args)**
this can help in providing extra security.
Any suggestion or even hint can be helpful for my designing the custom JVM.

Comment: Customizing the JVM is probably the wrong path here. If someone has access to your server to the point that they can control how java is invoked, you're in some pretty deep trouble already. I would focus on making the Java code itself secure -- ensure there are no injection attacks, protect against cross-site scripting if appropriate, etc.

Comment: How a customized main method would be more secure?

Comment: This is an example of 'security by obscurity', which is regarded as fallacious. You should concentrate on real attacks and real solutions.

Comment: Yes, I will be taking care of other security mechanism, but I wanted to hide entry point of the code so that some other java code can't invoke my program intentionnally or unintentionally. I will be installing a program specific JRE to invoke the code, instead of using JRE installed on server. I hope we can customize JRE/JVM default behaviour.

Comment: Some other Java code *can* invoke your code, intentionally or otherwise, if it happens to have a method of the correct name and signature. You are relying on that remaining a secret, which is security by obscurity, and even then it isn't complete protection. And what happens when they want to upgrade the Java version? You're barking up the wrong tree here.

Comment: Or, somebody could just change the contents of your jar so that the magically-invoked class contains the code they want, not the code you want.